# limit all products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to limit all products. For example, if I have 135 products stored in the database, then I want to display 50 (latest) products.

[image]

Is there a hook or can I modify any file?

Note:I don't want to limit the products per page using posts_per_page

I wrote this function. Yes, it works, but it doesn't change the fields of the whole table. For example, ALL remains the same
[image]

```
function limit_total_admin_products($where, $query) {
global $wpdb;

if (is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('post_type') === 'product') {
    $max_products = 50;
    $where = " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (
        SELECT ID FROM (
            SELECT ID
            FROM {$wpdb->posts}
            WHERE post_type = 'product'
            ORDER BY ID DESC
            LIMIT {$max_products}
        ) as latest_products
    )";
}

return $where;}
add_filter('posts_where', 'limit_total_admin_products', 10, 2);
```